# Autoprefixer CLI promise is not defined

Tags: css, command-line-interface, autoprefixer

I am working on a project where I mainly use CSS (SASS) and just a few js. I found out about Autoprefixer a couple days ago and tried to use it by CLI. But each time I get the same error, "promise is not defined". I tried to fix this problem, but I only found answer for grunt or other things. No solutions for CLI use. Do you have any idea on how can I fix it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I tried many things then I come with a solution.

`npm i -g es6-promise` 
Then, in lazy-result.js file that gave me the error on promise, I add at the first line:
`var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;`

It seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Autoprefixer has become a part of PostCSS. To be able to use Autoprefixer as a CLI Tool you will have to use the [PostCSS-CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-cli) module.
`npm install --global postcss-cli autoprefixer`

Here is an example of how to use the module:
`postcss --use autoprefixer *.css -d build/`

Comment: Okay. You might want to check your node version and update it. Otherwise checkout a [promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill), which might solve the problem for you.

Comment: I used `node -v`, I get `v0.10.32`, then `npm i -g node`, same version.
I'm not sure about your promise polyfill. I did check the link, but it's not for the CLI is it ?